# .Net Core Fastest Way to Check for Existing Ids (Large Dataset)

Tags: c#, .net-core

Once a week I run a background service that checks an export file which contains a list of  ids that may need to be merged into my database. Currently my database has ~3.5 million records in it.

The first thing I do after getting all the possible new ids from the file is check if the id is already in the database. This check takes around 9-10 minutes to complete. This is a background job so its not the end of the world, I just wonder if it can be more efficient.

Here is what I'm currently using (seems to be the fastest way I've found)

```
var newIds = new List<int>();     
var existingIds = _context.{currentRecords}.Select(i => i.Id).ToList();
var ingestIds = ingestList.Select(i => i.Id).ToList();
newIds = ingestIds.Where(id => !existingIds.Contains(id)).ToList();
```

other things i've tried which are slower

```
foreach (var id in ingestIds)
{
   if (!_context.{currentRecords}.Any(i => i.Id == id)) newIds.Add(id);
}
```

I've tried a couple of other slightly different methods based on searches, but they were slower and I've apparently mis-placed the code from those attempts. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You've got a database server lying around which is almost certainly much better at doing this check than your client code, especially if the number of rows you're importing is much less than the number of existing rows. Use `SqlBulkCopy` to send everything to a new table unconditionally, then do an `INSERT .. WHERE NOT EXISTS` or `MERGE` using the existing and new tables.

Comment: How many ids on average are in the list from the file?

Comment: Also, what Jeroen said - this is really best done at the data layer level. You're pulling 3+ million records into memory to do this no matter how you implement it client side, which is not really a great idea.

Comment: usually in the neighborhood of 200 new, I have seen it as high as 8000 though.

Comment: I should also clarify, the check is also there because if an ID is new, I need to hit a 3rd party api and gather additional information  about the property before saving.

Comment: Even if additional client-side processing is required, sending over the IDs (through a table-valued parameter, for example) and getting back the list of IDs that are actually new will still beat downloading all existing IDs first. 8000 vs 3.5M is easy math -- you want to bring the small pile of data to the big pile of data, not the other way around.

Comment: It's hard for me to test anything out without good test data, but I'd say avoid ToList and use IEnumerable and intersect https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-6.0 - also yeah if you CAN, use sql to do this. It's going to be faster than anything client side.

Comment: Yeah took a second to process @JeroenMostert, but my brain got there eventually, I think I will give that a shot, it sounds like a good  way to go!

Comment: @JeroenMostert Would you mind adding your initial response as an answer so I can mark it as such for future visitors. It's the answer full stop. it Took me a while to get around to testing, but that 9-10 minute task, now takes ~10-20 seconds....so I cant say thanks enough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you get all the data to the client-side. Maybe you can try this;

```
    List<TKey> ingestIds = ingestList.Select(i => i.Id);

    var existingIds = _context.{currentRecords}.Where(i => ingestIds.Contains(i.Id)).Select(i => i.Id).ToList();

    var newIds = ingestIds.Except(existingIds);
```

This will execute `where` and `select` operations in database.

Comment: Ok so egg on face moment.... I rode the struggle bus making the SQL stored procedures and extra tables to do this(which works very well!) but with just .Except its done even faster, thank you, I quit, but really thank you!

Comment: @user7704925: The extra table can still be useful if the list of IDs gets big enough, as there are limits to how many values can be transmitted this way (or transmitted efficiently, at least) that a table doesn't suffer from, plus a table can benefit from indexing more than a list of values can. Both techniques are good to have in your arsenal.

Comment: I agree, it was very helpful to have done it with the extra table and use stored procedures, but as for now, the second way suites my needs wonderfully! I have some other things I plan to use bulk copy for in the future as well, so speedy!